# Create a number pyramid using an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to ask the user via a prompt to `Enter a number:`. Then, I want to use an array to print the numbers to the screen like a "normal pyramid" and an "upside-down pyramid".

I want to make an input field and a button next to it. Inside the input side you can give a number between 1-20 when you click on the button it should show this:

[image: Screenshot of pyramid ascending]

But only till the number you put inside the field so if you put 8 the pyramid only show 1-8 and not 9-20.

[image: Screenshot of pyramid descending]

```
var number = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];

question();
function question() {
    if(question != 1) {
        prompt("enter a number.", "20");
        for (var a = 0; a < question; a++) {
    
        }
    }
}
```

I tried doing this, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: It's because your `for` loop body is empty

Comment: i did now put 20 in the loop because you can answer 1-20 but it still doesnt work

Comment: What is `question != 1` for? `question` is the name of the function right? And whats is the purpose of the array `number` after all If you want to get user's input? Also, I suggest you to check [prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) docs, you're using it wrong.

Comment: i need to loop the array to make it work right?

Comment: these are called "orthogonal triangles" - not "pyramids"

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a pair of simple nested loops as shown below.

```js
var num = prompt("enter a number",20)

for(var i=0;i<=num;i++) {
  var s = "";
  for(var j=0;j<=i;j++) {
    s+=j
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += (s + "<br>")
}

for(var i=num;i>=0;i--) {
  var s = "";
  for(var j=0;j<=i;j++) {
    s+=j
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += (s + "<br>")
}
```

```html
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Inside the `question()` method we build the string with nested loops.

- Then we concat the values up to the value of the outer loop and then insert this string into the result and do the newline(in reasons of html I do a "<br>")
- For the upside down orthogonal triangles we are doing the same just in the outer loop starting from the input value and not from zero and decrement instead of incrementing the indice.

```js
function question() {

  let val = parseInt(prompt("enter a number.", "20"));
  let res = "";
  let temp = "";

  for (let a = 0; a <= val; a++) {
    for (let b = 0; b <= a; b++) {
      temp += "" + b;
    }
    res += "" + temp + "<br>"
    temp = "";
  }

  res += "<br>"


  for (let b = val; b >= 0; b--) {
    for (let c = 0; c <= b; c++) {
      temp += c
    }
    res += temp + "<br>"
    temp = "";

  }
  document.getElementById("in").innerHTML = res;

}
```

```html
<p id="in"></p> 
<button onclick="question()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example I use `slice()` and `join()` methods

```js
var number = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];

for (var i = 0; i <= number.length; i++) {
    var x = number.slice(0, i).join('');
    console.log(x);
}

for (var i = number.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    var x = number.slice(0, i).join('');
    console.log(x);
}
```

**HTML Example:**

```js
function piramid() {
    var res = document.querySelector('div');
    res.innerHTML = '';

    var n = +document.querySelector('input').value;
    var number = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        number.push(i);                
    }

    for (var i = 0; i <= number.length; i++) {
        var x = number.slice(0, i).join('');
        res.innerHTML += x + '<br>';
    }

    for (var i = number.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        var x = number.slice(0, i).join('');
        res.innerHTML += x + '<br>';
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number">
<button onclick="piramid()">Click me</button>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be more short and quick:

```js
var n=20;
n=parseInt(prompt("Enter number",n),10);
var s="";
for(var j=0;j<2;j++)
   for(var i=0;i<n+1;i++){
     if(j==0)s+=i;
     console.log(s);
     if(j==1)s=s.substr(0,s.length-((n-i)>9?2:1));
}
```